# AngularJS redirectTo is no finding the right path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have a configuration for my $routeprovider that when I change the  `redirectTo: function() {'/dasboard'}` to  `redirectTo: function() {'/home'}`, it goes to the otherwise route, `.otherwise({redirectTo: '/404'});`.

The home.html and the dashboard.html are at the same level folder, and I'm using this [Template](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/flatify-responsive-admin-web-app-WB0977873). What could be the problem?

```
app.config([
'$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

  return $routeProvider

   .when('/', {

                redirectTo: function() {return '/home'} /*before 'return /dasboard'*/
    })

   .when('/login', {

               templateUrl: '/views/pages/signin.html'
  })

  .when('/signup', {

               templateUrl: '/views/signup.html'
  })

  .when('/dashboard', {

                templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html'
  })

  .otherwise({

    redirectTo: '/404'
  });
}
```

]);

Comment: is this an MVC application?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having, is that you are redirecting to a route that does not exist. Then you are attempting to fallback on another route that is also undefined.

You need to declare the "home" and "404" routes.

```
.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
})
.when('/404', {
    templateUrl: 'views/404.html'
})
```

The route that you are redirecting to needs to have a template. The route you are redirecting from does not.

You can read more about the `$routeProvider` here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: I don't wanna use template or templateUrl I need to redirect to different location because is for a longing page and the template is going to load the view but the nav-controls and the other side menus still available; please explain I think you are telling me that I Have to create the rout in order to usi the redirect? make sense Ill try it